# Install Outlook 2003 alongside Office 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-outlook-2003

I have several mails created earlier in outlook PST files compliant with 97-2003 format. I may need to just refer to them if required. These PSTs open in Office 2013 but give some weird errors on certain folders e.g. Sent Items or Inbox folders are just blank. It does not display any mails. I believe these PSTs are not compatible with Office 2013.

My plan is to remove Outlook 2013 from Office package, install only Outlook component from MS Office 2003 on a separate partition not mixed with Office 2013.
Is such a configuration supported? If not is there any workaround to make it work? OS is Windows 7 64.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean with the "separate partition"-thing... i would use a virtual machine! - and if the files respectively the information in it is needed in future, finally migrate it.

Comment: ...or even better ditch proprietary formats and convert to free ones! ;-)

Comment: By separate partition I mean not mixed with the Install Path of Office 2013. If Office 2013 is in C:\Program Files, I will install Outlook 2003 elsewhere say at E:\MSOffice.

Answer (score 0):

- first i'm pretty sure mixing isn't officially supported. and also in particular MS Office 2003 is no more supported since 2014 (regular support ended 2009).
- then different paths are nice (partitions are irrelevant), but at least at the registry it get mixed... so i would advise against this (especially at a production-environment).

as already mentioned... if there is no way to get the PST-file working with the new Outlook, i would use a different or a virtual system (e.g. virtualbox) with the original Outlook installed to get access to the information you need.
if this works, a normal migration should be possible, if not you've got "bigger problems" with your PST-file...!

---

possible errors and things to take care:

- are you sure the PST files didn't get corrupt?
- was the PST-backup created/copied while Outlook was NOT running?
- have you used the import-function in the new Outlook?